# Excel date parameter in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, oracle, odbc

I use  an SQL query to retrieve a data table from an oracle database with excel.

When a fixed date is used I get this request:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Date > {ts '2014-09-30 00:00:00'}
```

What I would like to do is replace the fixed date by a date from a cell.
I tried the folowing:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Date > ?
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Date > {ts ?}
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Date > {ts '?'}
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Date > {ts [?]}
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Date > {ts ['?']}
```

None of it worked. I don't know where to go from there.
In the end I'd like the date cell to work in either american (12/31/2014) or international (31/12/2014) configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is stored in the cell A1 using Excel date format then to pass it as a parameter to the query you must do as follow:

1 - Transform the date format to a correct date string in cell B2 for obdc:

```
= LOWER(TEXT(D2,"dd-mmmm-yyyy"))
```

2 - Pass the B2 cell as a paremeter with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.Date > ?
```

Comment: The dateFormat depends on your regional settings if like me you're in Switzerland (French part) it must be `"jj-mm-aaaa` (where j = jour = day / a = année = year). So check with your regional settings and apply accordingly.