# Excel timestamp as parameter in MS Query results in Conversion Error

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, remedy

If found this thread, but unfortunately it didn't help:

[Excel date parameter in SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130283/excel-date-parameter-in-sql-query/38784876?noredirect=1#comment64940365_38784876)

I tried the solution in the thread above and I get the following results:

Using the ODBC connection I have to use the below in order for it to accept the query:

```
HPD_Help_Desk.Submit_Date > { ts '2016-08-01 00:00:00' }
```

I've replaced this to the below, cause there is no other way (that I've found) it takes the parameter

```
HPD_Help_Desk.Submit_Date > ?
```

My Original Cell value is:

```
7/31/2016
```

With the formula I tried several formats

```
=LOWER(TEXT(C2,"YYYY-MM-DD"))
=LOWER(TEXT(C2,"dd-mmmm-yyyy"))
```

when I try the solution above I get the error. I get the same error if I just point straight to the date value in Excel:

```
[AR System ODBC Driver]Conversion Error
```

if I try this formula

```
=LOWER(TEXT(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

I get the exact timestamp string '2016-07-01 00:00:00' but then I get:

```
[AR System ODBC Driver]Unrecognised Data Format
```

Any ideas if it's a limitation, or I'm just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after almost tearing all my hair out, I've found the solution.

The expected format from the [AR System ODBC Driver] we use is:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS.FF
```

for example:

```
'2016-08-01 00:00:00.00'
```

And yes, the [.] dot before the milliseconds is not a typo...

I hope it will help somebody else struggling with this.